# Catching permission errors with invoke-sqlcmd and powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am running the following PowerShell script, and what strikes me is that its not catching permission specific errors. I know that the error action has been set to continue, which is what I want, however I would like to track such errors but for them not to terminate the loop that I am running.

```
$in_sql_deployment_instance = 'SQL_SERVER'
$target_dba_database = 'TEST'
$query = "RAISERROR (15600,-1,-1, 'mysp_CreateCustomer') WITH log;  "

try{
    $null =  invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$in_sql_deployment_instance" -Query $query -Database $target_dba_database -Querytimeout 60 -OutputSqlErrors $true -ConnectionTimeout 10 -ErrorAction Continue 

}
catch
{

    $error_message = $_.Exception.Message
    write-output "Error occured $error_message"

}
```

I get the error back on the Ps console, but it appears I cannot catch the error etc or store in a variable.

```
invoke-sqlcmd : Only System Administrator can specify WITH LOG option for RAISERROR command.
At line:2 char:14
+ ...    $null =  invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$in_sql_deployment_instanc ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, in order for the catch to be executed, you would need to set your `-ErrorAction` to `Stop`.

I suppose what you could do is:
set: `$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"` at the top of your cmdlet and then have `-ErrorAction stop` on the call to `invoke-sql`, this should cause it to drop into the `catch` but continue to behave with the `continue` behaviour in the rest of your script.

Another option if you want to leave `-ErrorAction continue` would be to also set `-ErrorVariable invokeSqlError` and then check if that variable contains a value. If it does an error has occurred.

Something like:

```
if ($invokeSqlError){
    write-output "Error occured $invokeSqlError"
}
```